# How to find multiple instances of same character on single line?

Tags: search, regular-expression

I have a CSV that uses ,(comma) as the delimiter. This CSV is nearly 20K lines long and there are 10 instances where a comma was used INSIDE the data. These errant commas are breaking my processor.

In VIM, how would you locate ONLY the lines that have more than 1 comma?

I can find all commas using

```
:%s/,//gn
```

This tells me I have 17655 commas on 17646 lines. There should only be 17646 commas, 1 per line, in the entire file. What is an easy way to locate any line with more than one comma on it?

Comment: If it's just the lines with more than one comma, you could search `/,.*,/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two expressions offhand that may work for you. They both worked on some quick, limited test data I tried. The first expression is

```
\(.\{-},\)\{2,}
```

This translates to "match at least 2 sequences of (as few as possible of anything followed by a comma)." In other words this tries to find matches of two or more sequences of comma-delimited text ranges.

Another is

```
.\{-},\@<=.*,
```

Which is "find anything followed by a comma, but only if immediately prior to that you could find as few as possible of anything followed by a comma."

I'm not sure if one or the other is more preferable. I find the first one easier to reason about, even though I came up with the second, more complex one first. You *may* need to anchor them with `^` to the start of the line.

[Karl Yngve Lervåg's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6563/72) has an even simpler regex that works just as well as my overengineered options.

With them, you can use the `global` command (`:help global`) to operate on the matching lines with some Ex command: `:g/.\{-},\@<=.*,/d` for example, will delete all the lines with more than one comma in them.

Comment: The second one worked perfect for my needs. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9):

A simple search should suffice:

```
/,.*,
```

This will match any line that has at least two commas.

Comment: Well, there's nothing like regex to make me feel like I'm over-complicating everything. :(

Comment: @JoshPetrie While we are complicating... `/,.*,`

Comment: @muru I think it is convenient to include the starting `/^.*`, in order to match only once per line (cf. the original question).

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg because of greedy matching, I'd think it would match only once per line anyway.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right! I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!